Why is a monkeypatch `String#to_regexp` called by Regexp.union
I'm upgrading a rails application to Rails 7. One gotcha I found is this monkeypatch:
class String
  def to_regexp
    Regexp.new(self)
  end
end

That little snippet blows up under Rails 7 because it resolved IRB to v1.14.1, where this line is present:
    ASSIGN_OPERATORS_REGEXP = Regexp.union(%w[= += -= *= /= %= **= &= |= &&= ||= ^= <<= >>=])

I inserted a debugger into the monkeypatch to try to trace it out, but there's no obvious call stack frame where to_regexp is getting called between Regexp.union and the monkeypatched String.to_regexp.
Here's how it can be reproduced:
irb(main):063* class String
irb(main):064*   def to_regexp
irb(main):065*     puts "String#to_regexp called"
irb(main):066*     Regexp.new(self)
irb(main):067*   end
irb(main):068> end
=> :to_regexp
irb(main):070> Regexp.union
=> /(?!)/
irb(main):071> Regexp.union %w[:=]
String#to_regexp called
=> /:=/
irb(main):072> Regexp.union %w[:= aabb]
String#to_regexp called
String#to_regexp called
=> /(?-mix::=)|(?-mix:aabb)/
irb(main):073> Regexp.union %w[:= aabb +=]
String#to_regexp called
String#to_regexp called
String#to_regexp called
(irb):66:in `initialize': target of repeat operator is not specified: /+=/ (RegexpError)
    from (irb):66:in `new'
    from (irb):66:in `to_regexp'
    from (irb):73:in `union'
    from (irb):73:in `<main>'


Check RegExp.try_convert then you'll have to dig into the re.c in the source to get to the actual call.

@muistooshort interesting, thank you! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it. If not, I'll self answer.
